# Feed / log / page of Windows and OSX Updates

Tags: windows, macos, updates, windows-update

Just wondering if anyone knows of a page / xml feed or something which I can monitor so I can quickly see if any new updates have been released for Windows/OSX.

So instead of running Windows/Software update, I can just check this page (automate it) and tell instantly if anything new has come out.

Ideally this shouldn't be a file on the computer, but something online.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows**

You can use [Google](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=windows+patch+tuesday+notifications) to find information to questions like this. Using Google you would have found [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/advance.mspx).

> Sign up for comprehensive alerts (including bulletin advance notification) via e-mail or RSS feed on the [Microsoft Technical Security Notifications page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/dd252948.aspx).

**OS X**

Apple doesn't offer this service.